# how to use nested loop join instead of block nested loop join in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

For the sake of comparison, I am looking for a way to disable block nested loop join and use a simple nested loop join, instead.
Based on MySQL's reference manual, they are both implemented:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/nested-loop-joins.html
But I've failed to find out how to alter the options to do so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fine tune the behaviour of the optimizer by setting the [optimizer_switch](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/switchable-optimizations.html) system variable:

> The optimizer_switch system variable enables control over optimizer behavior. Its value is a set of flags, each of which has a value of on or off to indicate whether the corresponding optimizer behavior is enabled or disabled. This variable has global and session values and can be changed at runtime. The global default can be set at server startup.
>
> [...]
>
> - Block Nested-Loop Flags
>
>   block_nested_loop (default on)
>
>   Controls use of BNL join algorithm.

To completely disable *block nested join* and using default values for everything else, you can use

```
SET optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off';
```

An alternative is to use [Optimizer hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html),

> Another way to control the optimizer is by using optimizer hints, which can be specified within individual statements. Because optimizer hints apply on a per-statement basis, they provide finer control over statement execution plans than can be achieved using optimizer_switch. For example, you can enable an optimization for one table in a statement and disable the optimization for a different table. Hints within a statement take precedence over optimizer_switch flags.
>
> [...]
>
> BNL, NO_BNL: Enable or disable BNL for the specified tables.

You can use e.g.

```
SELECT /*+ NO_BNL() */ t1.* FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3;
```

Comment: Using an optimizer hint to disable BNL as recommended here worked for me.